# Android 9.0 as Target Android Version in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2017, I am able to set Target Android Version as 9.0 but on Visual Studio 2019, it doesnt offer me.

[image]

max. it offers 8.1 version as shown below. I wonder if there is a breaking change and it has something to do with above "compile using target framework", so it automatically uses this setting as Target Android Version. Because when I build my project in VS2019, it builds fine.

[image]

i have it v9.0(level 28.0.2) installed and it is shown in Vs2017 but not in Vs2019 as target Android version but as Target Framework.

EDIT:
here is how Android SDK looks like. as you can see that Android 9.0 is installed.

[image]

Comment: run Android SDK manager and install Android 9 tools

Comment: Need to have a look at screen capture of Android SDK Manager in VS2019.

Comment: I have the same issue. Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.2 is installed.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT it is installed. otherwise first screenshot wont appear. beside that as i wrote i am running vs2017 side by side and they share same sdk path. Vs2017 displays it but not vs2019. I am not a newbie, working with xamarin since 2015. I wont make this question otherwise.  i will update my question with screenshot later when i have access to my pc.

Comment: I have Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.2 installed and Android SDK Platform 28 installed.  But I am not seeing Android 9.0 (API Level 28 - Pie) in the list of possible "Target Android Version" using VS2019.  I confirmed, I DO see Android 9.0 (API Level 28 - Pie) in VS2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that it is a bug in VS2019. I have asked it over xamarin gitter and
reply from Microsoft engineers:

> we have fixed it and the fix will ship soon. For now, you can manually
>   edit the manifest and set it there, and everything will work.

EDIT: latest VS 2019 update has a fix for this problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.0.3

Comment: If I change the target sdk version from 27 to 28 in the manifest, now the target sdk version dropdown is blank.  Is this part of the bug, or does this indicate the install of 28 may not have been correct?

Comment: Hi, Could you please share xamarin gitter link,it will be helpful ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT you mean https://gitter.im/xamarin/xamarin-android url? because i cant make a direct url reference to answer.

Comment: @MarkErickson i just use vs2017 side by side and i do build and archiving yet with it. vs2019 i use only for debugging because it seems faster than vs2017. i hope that they will fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud install Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.02 In this case you can acess the adress https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools and download it.

After this, restart your pc and open the visual studio 2019.
Open your xamarin project, select Xamarin.Android project go to properties and change the target Android version to Android 9.0

Comment: i have explicitly wrote that it is already installed. please read the question carefully before you answer. thanks

Comment: I commented you 10 minutes after you posted the topic. There wasn't pictures, few describe about the problem. But ok man. did you resolve your problem in android? Thanks

Comment: picture was requested by Microsoft guy but i have written the sentence "i have it v9.0(level 28.0.2) installed and it is shown in Vs2017".  yes I was told that it is a bug and will be published in the next update of Vs2019

Answer (score 0):

batmaci.

You are not the only one. I have exactly the same situation. Neither Minimum Android Version or Target Android Version are even populated when my project is opened with VS2019, where all is normal with VS2017. Not only are they not populated, but like you, I also can't set Target Android Version because Android 9.0 doesn't exist in the list. My guess is that it is not correctly reading the AndroidManifest when loading the project. Updating all the SDK tools resulted in no change. Since the correct settings are in the manifest it doesn't seem to have any effect on the apk produced. The apk runs fine on my Android 9 phone.

The other pain is that you can't remove a reference, because the right-click menu has lost that option. The only way I can get the remove item on the menu is to unload the project, and view the csproj file and then reload it with the file still open. Then like magic, the Remove item is back and you can swap out, for instance, a debug dll for a release dll.

I'm using VS2019 16.0.1 Preview 1.0, so I guess if it is not fixed in that, it sure won't be fixed in the release version of VS2019. Strange that others here don't have the problem.